# How to choose the initial values of the cache in dynamic programming?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

Whenever I write a code with a solution using dynamic programming my code looks something like this:

```
table[1000][1000]  //the cache to store initialized with a certain_value
function(parameters i,j){
    if(base_condition){
        return base_value
    }
    if(table[i][j] != certain_value){
        return table[i][j];
    }
    answer = some operation using function();
    table[i][j] = answer;
    return answer;
}
```

Usually I choose this `certain_value` as `-1`. But now I am writing a code in which the function can return all real numbers. So how do I choose this value or should I change my approach.

Comment: Warning: `table[1000][1000]` could be a stack-killer

Comment: you are right, I know I should be using the heap. Do you have any suggestions on    how to create such a cache?

Comment: Use an `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a parallel data structure of `bool` elements to represent which elements have been cached.

Alternatively, you can use `std::optional` as the element type, and let the empty value represent a non-cached value.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a boolean array. If you once calculated for (i,j) then keep true on that  boolean[i][j]. So when you are testing whether this state is precached or not just test using whether boolean[i][j] is true or not. If true then returned the stored value from table array.

```
boolean visited[1000][1000]={false}
table[1000][1000]  //the cache to store intialized with a certain_value
function(parameters i,j){
    if(base_condition){
        return base_value
    }
    if(visited[i][j] == true{
        return table[i][j];
    }
    answer = some operation using function();
    table[i][j] = answer;
    visited[i][j]=true;
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other approaches you could take. If you want to stick with the approach you are used to, this question is not about dynamic programming so much as it is about [sentinel values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value). What value can you use as a sentinel if all real numbers are possible?

One detail I notice is that all *real* numbers are possible. That's both good and bad. It's bad because a computer cannot represent every real number, but presumably that has already been accounted for. It's good because most methods used to represent real numbers include some values that are not real numbers. The `float` or `double` values that most obviously are not real numbers are the [NaNs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/quiet_NaN) (Not a Number). Another option is [infinity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity). In either case, [`std::is_finite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite) can be used to detect if the sentinel value has been changed to a real number.

Strictly speaking, it is not guaranteed that these values will be available, but in practice they likely are. When they are available, they can be used as sentinels as long as your special function cannot return them. (Double check the claim "all real numbers are possible" in terms of `float`/`double` values — can the function return a value that is not a real number?)